# Help fix an ugly axis

Tags: plotting

I am trying to plot a cuboid without box using Graphics3D, however the y-axis looks ugly, "floating" above the cube. The y-axis should join the other two at the origin. Thank you!

```
Graphics3D[{RGBColor[113/255, 190/255, 236/255], Cuboid[{0, 0, 0}]}, 
 Axes -> True, PlotRange -> {{0, 2}, {0, 2}, {0, 2}}, Boxed -> False]
```

[image]

Comment: Try `AxesOrigin -> {0, 0, 0}`. Possible duplicate of http://mathematica.stackexchange.com/q/21605/131.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

If you do not want to axes to dynamically redraw themselves to stay in view as you rotate then you can use `AxesEdge` to fix their location.

```
Graphics3D[{RGBColor[113/255, 190/255, 236/255], Cuboid[{0, 0, 0}]},
 Axes -> True, AxesEdge -> {{-1, -1}, {-1, -1}, {-1, -1}},
 PlotRange -> {{0, 2}, {0, 2}, {0, 2}},
 Boxed -> False]
```

[image]

But in this case the default viewpoint hides the axes. Either rotate or use `ViewPoint`.

```
Graphics3D[{RGBColor[113/255, 190/255, 236/255], Cuboid[{0, 0, 0}]},
 Axes -> True, AxesEdge -> {{-1, -1}, {-1, -1}, {-1, -1}},
 PlotRange -> {{0, 2}, {0, 2}, {0, 2}},
 ViewPoint -> {2, 2, 2},
 Boxed -> False]
```

[image]

Hope this helps.

Comment: `ViewPoint -> {2, 2, 0.5}` is a little better, actually.

Answer (score 3):

You may also do like this:

```
    Graphics3D[{RGBColor[113/255, 190/255, 236/255], Cuboid[{0, 0, 0}]}, 
 Axes -> True, PlotRange -> {{0, 2}, {0, 2}, {0, 2}}, Boxed -> False, 
 AxesOrigin -> {0, 0, 0}]
```

[image]

and like this:

```
    Graphics3D[{RGBColor[113/255, 190/255, 236/255], Cuboid[{0, 0, 0}], 
   Red, Thick, Line[{{0, 0, 0}, {2, 0, 0}}], 
   Line[{{0, 0, 0}, {0, 2, 0}}], Line[{{0, 0, 0}, {0, 0, 2}}]}, 
  Axes -> False, PlotRange -> {{0, 2}, {0, 2}, {0, 2}}, 
  Boxed -> False] /. Line -> Composition[Arrow, Tube]
```

[image]

Have fun!