# Positioning labels in 3D plots ... again

Tags: plotting, labeling

I am looking for a way to manually control the positioning of labels in a 3D plot. For this purpose I used to follow the methods of the accepted answers in:

[Axes Origin & Labels in 3D Plot](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/questions/21605/axes-origin-labels-in-3d-plot)

[Manually assigning Axes label position in Plot3D](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/questions/105715/manually-assigning-axes-label-position-in-plot3d)

which basically achieves that using `Show` and something like

`Graphics3D[Text["x", Scaled[{0.5, -0.2, -0.2}] ]`

I'm guessing this has something to do with the version 13.1, but this no longer works. In this version I can't even reproduce the accepted solutions above anymore. The labels simply don't show up.

Example:

`Show[{Plot3D[x^2 + y^2 + 3, {x, -3, 3}, {y, -3, 3},PlotRange -> {-1, 20}],Graphics3D[{Text["x", Scaled[{-.05, .5, 0}], {0, -1}], Text["y", Scaled[{.5, -.05, 0}], {0, -1}], Text["z", Scaled[{.5, .5, 1.1}]]}]}]`

returns:

[image]

no x y z labels...

I think the problem is that `Scaled` brings the label outside the boundingbox of `Graphics3D`, but `PlotRange` doesn't fix that. I can play with `Scaled` to bring the labels into the plot. In this picture it still may look fine to bring the labels inside, but in other cases it doesn't.

Also, if possibe, I'd like the answer not to involve the function `Text`, because for aesthetic reasons I use the package `Matex`, to produce labels as in

`Graphics3D[Inset[MaTeX["x"], Scaled[{0.5, -0.2, -0.2}] ] ]`

and hence some functionalities of Text may not carry over. Alternatives to this approach are also welcome though. Thank you.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Here is a more precise way to do that where you can arbitrary control the positions of labels and even rotate

```
lebl = MaTeX["\\color{red}\\text{Lable}", FontSize -> 14];
axeslebl = MaTeX[#, FontSize -> 14] & /@ {"X", "Y", "Z"};
```

then you get (Note that `LM Roman 12` is the same font as `MaTeX`)

```
Plot3D[x^2 + y^2 + 3, {x, -3, 3}, {y, -3, 3}, PlotRange -> {-1, 20}, 
 LabelStyle -> {FontFamily -> "LM Roman 12", Black, FontSize -> 14}, 
 Epilog -> {Text[lebl, Scaled[{.5, 1.1}]], 
   Rotate[Text[axeslebl[[1]], Scaled[{.25, 0.02}]], -\[Pi]/10], 
   Rotate[Text[axeslebl[[2]], Scaled[{.94, 0.2}]], \[Pi]/3], 
   Rotate[Text[axeslebl[[3]], Scaled[{-0.1, 0.5}]], \[Pi]/1.8]}, 
 ImagePadding -> 40, AspectRatio -> 1]
```

[image]

Answer (score 3):

- For `Graphics3D`,`Inset` work.

```
ResourceFunction["MaTeXInstall"][];
<< MaTeX`
Graphics3D[{{Opacity[.2], Cuboid[]}, 
  Inset[MaTeX["x", Magnification -> 4], {0.5, -0.2, -0.2}], 
  Inset[MaTeX["O", Magnification -> 4], {0.5, 0.5, 0.5}]}, 
 Boxed -> False]
```

[image]

- `Plot3D`, we can also use `AxesLabel` and `Labeled`.

```
<< MaTeX`

Plot3D[Labeled[x^2 + y^2 + 3, 
  MaTeX["\\mathcal{A}", Magnification -> 2], {.5, .5}, 
  Background -> None], {x, -3, 3}, {y, -3, 3}, PlotRange -> {-1, 20}, 
 AxesLabel -> {MaTeX["x", Magnification -> 3], 
   MaTeX["y", Magnification -> 3], MaTeX["z", Magnification -> 3]}]
```

[image]

Comment: What font is`MaTeX` using? Very pretty!

Comment: @NicholasG Here is the default font of LaTeX ,we can set another fonts as show in http://szhorvat.net/pelican/latex-typesetting-in-mathematica.html

Comment: Many thanks. I do not see the font Latin Modern in my PC installation of 13.1. There is a Modern No. 20, which seems somewhat close.

Comment: `Graphics3D[{{Opacity[.2], Cuboid[]}, 
  Inset[MaTeX["x", Magnification -> 4], {0.5, -.2, 0}, Automatic, 
   Automatic, AngleVector[-π/10]], 
  Inset[MaTeX["y", Magnification -> 4], {1.2, .5, 0}, Automatic, 
   Automatic, AngleVector[-π/6]], 
  Inset[MaTeX["z", Magnification -> 4], {1.2, 1, .5}], 
  Inset[MaTeX["O", Magnification -> 4], {0.5, 0.5, 0.5}]}, 
 Boxed -> False]`

Comment: I am not sure I understand your answer. If LaTeX uses the font Latin Modern, as it seems to do, then the font Latin Modern must be a publicly available font, and I should be able to install it and use it directly from Mathematica without having to install MaTeX. No?

Comment: @NicholasG  I have install TeXLive 2022, there lots of fonts in this TeX system.

Comment: @NicholasG  In my computer,I have install TeXLive 2022, and MaTeX use the available fonts in TeXLive 2022 and in the Win system.